# Weaviate sub-selection query using python client

Tags: weaviate

how to query with subselection ?
f.e. I have an attribute in my schema with:

```
{
      "dataType": ["geoCoordinates"],
      "description": "The geocoordinate of the company",
      "name": "coordinates"
  }
```

Now geoCoordinates have latitude and longitude as subselection
When query with

```
client.query.get(class_name=class_name, properties=[coordinates]).do()
```

I get the following error:

```
'Field "coordinates" of type "ArticlecoordinatesGeoCoordinatesObj" must have a sub selection.'
```

How to specify the sub-selection ?

Answer (score 2):

Duda from Weaviate here!

As `coordinates` is a [GeoCoordinates dataype](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/datatypes#datatype-geocoordinates), You now have to pass the subselection of fields you want to query. For instance:

```
coordinates = "coordinates{latitude longitude}"
```

So your python client query, considering you also have a "title" field would be:

```
client.query.get(class_name=class_name, properties=["title", "coordinates{latitude longitude}"]).do()
```

A **nice tip** is that you can always inspect the resulting graphql query using build(), like so:

```
client.query.get(class_name=class_name, properties=["title", "coordinates{latitude longitude}"]).build()
```

It will return you the exact graphql query generated, for instance:

'{Get{Article{title coordinates{latitude longitude}}}}'